# How do I remove all vowels from a string and return the result using a for loop?

Tags: javascript, string

I want to write a function that takes in a string and returns a new string with all vowels removed using a for loop. I have tried using various string methods with no luck.

Here's what my code looks like so far:

```
function disemvowel(string) {
  let newString = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (string[i] != "a" && string[i] != "e" && string[i] != "i" && string[i] != "o" && string[i] != "u") {
      return newString += string[i];
    };
  };
};
```

**Update**
The question was not a duplicate. Here is the solution I was looking for.

```
function disemvowel(string) {

  let vowels = {
    'a': true,
    'e': true,
    'i': true,
    'o': true,
    'u': true
  };

  let result = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    let letter = string[i].toLowerCase();
    if (!vowels[letter]) {
      result += string[i];
    }
  };
  return result;
};
```

Comment: As well as the duplicate question, you might want to know what's wrong with your function:  You switch between `str` and `string`; that needs to be consistent.  And you misplace your `return statement`.  Remove `return` and add `return newString` after the close of the `for`-loop block.

Comment: And by the way, I love your function name!

Comment: Hm my for loop is still not working despite the fixes. Thank you though!

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way would be the `replace` function with a regular expression:

```
function removeVowels( input ){
    return input.replace(/[aeiouAEIOU]/g, "");
}
```

Remark: This function does not test whether input is a String, it is assumed here.

As pointed out by Jonas Wilms, the same can be achieved in a shorter way by using the `i` (ignore case) flag with the regex:

```
function removeVowels( input ){
    return input.replace(/[aeiou]/gi, "");
}
```

Comment: You need the `g` flag, and with the `i` flag you can save the repetition of vowels

Comment: Thanks for the `g` flag. The i flag can be used here as well, that's true

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to do this with a for-loop or another simple way that isn't a shortcut expression like `.replace(/[aeiou]/ig,'')`